# How to hook into Devise action before facebook redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to hook into an action that will get called before devise users are redirected to facebook for login. The login link suggests I look into the passthru action in the omniauth_callbacks but that doesn't seem to work

```
user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path   GET|POST    /users/auth/facebook(.:format)  my_devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
```

Any ideas how to make a call before the redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find anything relevant to solving this?